# measure working set size of a thread?

Tags: multithreading, migration

info:
    it is stated in  [Understanding the Cost of Thread Migration for Multi-Threaded
Java Applications Running on a Multicore Platform](http://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=Understanding+the+Cost+of+Thread+Migration+for+Multi-Threaded+Java+Applications+Running+on+a+Multicore+Platform&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) :

1,

> primary cost of migration on multicore platforms is due to L2 cache misses.

2,

> threads with very small or very large working set sizes suffer the least from migration.
>   Maximal cache miss penalties result when the migrating thread has a working set size that nearly fills up the entire cache.

question:
    is there a way to determine working set size of specified thread (properly referred by TID) ? so to determine if thread migration is a major performance bottleneck.

Comment: This line of questions is staggering towards asking us to do research, rather than answering a specific code/design issue.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. maybe i can make it further clear: given a thread (referred to by TID) can i calculate size of its "working set" ? (and what exactly is "working set" ?)